How to format JSON output from Google App Script
I have a script setup in Google App Script to pull data from an API and then add that data to Google Sheets. Next i have a script that creates a JSON structure from the Google Sheets data. I am now trying to format the output of the data to fit in with another API.
Below is the script i am using and the output from JSON
function GETJOBDATA() {
  var url = "MYAPIURL";

    var headers = { "Accept": "application/json",
                   "Content-Type": "application/json",
                  "Authorization": "Basic "MYCODE"
                  };

      var options ={
                    "headers" : headers
                   };
       var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);

  
  const dataastext = response.getContentText()

  const data = JSON.parse(dataastext)

  const results = data.map (jobs =>{
    return [jobs["PositionID"],jobs["PositionTitle"],jobs["PositionIndustry"]]

  })

  return results

    // Execute function on request GET
    function doGet(e) {
  // Access data
  const data =  SpreadsheetApp.openById('GOOGLESHEETSID').getSheetByName('SHEETNAME').getDataRange().getValues();

  // Fetch data first row in lowercase
  const headings = data[0].map((val)=>{return val.toString().toLowerCase();});
  // Fetch data without the header
  const rows = data.slice(1);


  // Convert array to object format
  const temp = rows.map((row)=>{ // Loop through data
    const myObj={}; // Clear object
    headings.forEach((headings, index)=>{myObj[headings] = row[index];}) // Go through headers and join them the data of the same column
    return myObj; // Return the value
  })

  // Convert data to a JSON structure
  const output = JSON.stringify({data: temp})
  


  // Return JSON data
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(output).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
}


}

The JSON Output looks like this:
{ "data": { "fieldheader1": "result1", "feildheader2": "result2" },
I want to remove the data output and make it look more like the below:
{ { "fieldheader1": "result1", "feildheader2": "result2" },
I am quite new to this so any help would be hugely appreciated.

JSON.stringify({data: temp}) to JSON.stringify(temp)

@TheMaster I believe your comment is correct. Kindly post it as an answer so other people in the community, who may have the same concern, will know that theirs can be resolved.

Change
const output = JSON.stringify({data: temp})

to
const output = JSON.stringify(temp)

to remove the prefix data

@Chris-Ol I don't think changing this is the problem or has anything to do with your new problem. Consider asking a new question with [mcve]

Thank you for this @TheMaster, i have edited the code and this does work but then the headings are not applied to each set of the data so when i update the script the headings looks like this:
[
[
"Fieldheader1",
"Fieldheader2"
],
[
"Result1",
"Result2"
],
I would like the script to look like this:
{ { "fieldheader1": "result1", "feildheader2": "result2" },
I hope this makes sense.

@Chris-Ol Please ask a new question. See [ask]. (Make sure you're logging properly. IMO, this shouldn't happen at all)

And, for anyone wondering: it did indeed not happen (dixit OP in Staging Ground).
